# Ubuntu 12.04 server for ARM

Tags: 12.04, arm

I'm looking to download Ubuntu 12.04 server for ARM but I can't find it under the [ARM image web folder](http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/precise-updates/main/installer-armhf/current/images/armadaxp/netboot/) (I found only uImage and uInitrd).
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know netinstall is recommended. And here are two sites may be of help to you.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RootfsFromScratch